# Lotusscript View Selection Formula NOT usage

Tags: lotusscript

I have a selection formula below. I need to get one field value then the first 5 charachter of value should be added to selection formula. I could not find any sample or clue to start digging.

For example Value is "25.05.1258966"
what i need to do is get the first 5 char "**25.05**" then add to selection.

```
selection = {Form="FormName"} 
selection = selection + { & Date <= [} + doc.DateLast(0) +{] }
selection = selection + ???
```

UPDATE
Value ="25.05"
Selection = Selection + {@Left(FieldName,5)!=Value}

Comment: `@Left(YourField; 5)` ?

Comment: How can i use this in Lotusscript

Comment: Selection is in a lotusscript agent

Comment: In the @Left, use a semicolon to separate parameters

Answer (score 0):

If your server's date format is MM/DD/YYYY then:

```
selection = selection + { & Date <= [} + Mid$(doc.DateLast(0),3,2) + "/" + Left$(doc.DateLast(0),2) + "/2018" +{] }
```

I've added the `/2018` - not sure if it works without it, possibly.  Adjust to suit your server's date format.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like these I love to `split` that value into an array. Then I can pick any element from that array and re-join them the way you want.

Example:

```
Dim arr As Variant
Dim res As String

arr = Split(myValue, ".") 
res = arr(0) + "." + arr(1)
```

Of course only works for strings strictly following a given pattern

Comment: I have already got value that i wanted. My question is i could not write selection formula because selectioun should not contains that value. I mean in lotus client we use  formula for exception likevNOT [fieldname] = "value" So i would like to use same think in Lotusscript agent

Comment: Maybe you should explain first what you want to accomplish with your selection plus the greater context. Is this something like a NotesDatabase.Search thing? No chance to help you if you leave us guessing

Comment: NOT [fieldname] = "value" is valid syntax for a full text search formula. It is not valid syntax for a selection formula.

Answer (score 0):

```
& value!="abc
```

or

```
& !(value="abc")
```

These two tests produce different results when value contains a list.

Comment: Thank you. I think i could bot explain my problem clearly. I am sorry

Comment: view results according to this formula below should be changed. I do not know any other way to explain better :(( what i need is only the syntax of @Left formula in Lotusscript agent Value ="25.05" Selection = Selection + {@Left(FieldName,5)!=Value}

Comment: See my answer -- I have given you the formula for LotusScript.

Comment: selection = selection + { & Date <= [} + Mid$(doc.DateLast(0),3,2) + "/" + Left$(doc.DateLast(0),2) + "/2018" +{] }

Comment: Last attempt to get more info: you are looking for a LotusScript syntax to be used in an Agent which is supposed to do *what*? When you say "selection": what kind of selection should your code perform? NotesDatabase.Search? NotesDatabase.Ftsearch?